# How to import data from CSV file into Python with certain codes

Tags: python, csv

I have a file data.csv with data contents like:

```bash
    142.52  114.28  126.26  152.39  144.66  85.77   125.67  102.87  103.86  114.50
1   108.98  136.10  121.75  108.52  115.19  112.91  136.93  101.75  112.48  88.32
2   53.15   119.53  123.89  90.64   152.98  75.89   106.95  102.13  137.73  136.42
3   109.21  113.83  87.62   65.00   98.80   109.24  131.47  130.89  97.98   99.74
4   84.29   76.61   70.68   146.38  95.45   96.93   80.07   122.09  72.59   101.60
5   87.46   114.01  95.43   81.56   105.42  114.87  107.38  112.26  92.87   98.49
6   92.08   98.56   89.17   70.27   109.67  97.68   72.25   115.58  87.22   107.08
7   121.09  108.67  129.59  80.44   114.33  91.82   87.97   94.02   99.55   107.16
8   81.88   124.65  115.64  74.20   136.81  145.24  130.40  102.28  83.84   127.83
9   97.65   131.30  110.31  126.22  113.38  120.63  106.22  142.97  108.63  114.32
```

I would prefer using only Python's built-in libraries e.g. string methods split and strip, as well as the list method append to get the expected result.

Expected Output:

A single dimension list of floating point values contained in the file.

```py
[142.52, 114.28, 126.26, 152.39, 144.66, 85.77, 125.67, 102.87, ...]
```

Comment: Is this some kind of school assignment? It sounds that you just copy pasted the question from somewhere. Please first study and try by yourself and then if you have some specific question I'll be happy to help.

Comment: I helped in rewriting in a way I would have were I back in time. I hope it’s a bit clear now

Comment: @Alex B. Should I don’t see the index in your image, but it was there in your data sample. Should it be removed https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5sTb.png

Comment: You are expected to show us your current research and a *honest attempt*. Please read (again?) [ask] if you do not understand why.

Comment: What is the logic behind ignoring the values in the first column (from second line onwards)? Also, your required output is a list of strings which you erroneously describe as "floating point values"

Comment: just make your lines homogeneous by adding character like `0` at the start and then apply a single rule

Answer (score 0):

You should use pandas do import and work with dataframes.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
```

Pandas dataframes can do many interesting things, and works well with other libraries such as numpy for vectorized processes and with machine learning libraries such as sklearn, xgboost, catboost etc...

Edit:

```
import csv 
def load_numbers_from_csv(filename): 
    numbers = [] 
    with open(filename, 'r') as file: 
        csv_reader = csv.reader(file) 
        for row in csv_reader: 
            for number in row: 
                try: 
                    numbers.append(float(number)) 
                except ValueError: 
                    pass 
    return numbers
```

Comment: That would not return a single list and does go against using only built in packages 

Comment: Try this code:


    import csv

    def load_numbers_from_csv(filename):
        numbers = []
        with open(filename, 'r') as file:
            csv_reader = csv.reader(file)
            for row in csv_reader:
                for number in row:
                    try:
                        numbers.append(float(number))
                    except ValueError:
                        pass
        return numbers
    
    csv_filename = 'data.csv'
    numbers_list = load_numbers_from_csv(csv_filename)
    print(numbers_list)

Comment: @MatanBendak: code in comments in not easy to read. But you can edit your answer to propose an alternative way :-) . But beware: the sample code contains a line number starting from the second line.

Answer (score 0):

found a method to deal with it like a list
you can use numpy ndarray to read it
then del the first column
and flatten all element to a list
the file I used is here, you should save it as a txt file or a csv file

```
0   142.52  114.28  126.26  152.39  144.66  85.77   125.67  102.87  103.86  114.50
1   108.98  136.10  121.75  108.52  115.19  112.91  136.93  101.75  112.48  88.32
2   53.15   119.53  123.89  90.64   152.98  75.89   106.95  102.13  137.73  136.42
3   109.21  113.83  87.62   65.00   98.80   109.24  131.47  130.89  97.98   99.74
4   84.29   76.61   70.68   146.38  95.45   96.93   80.07   122.09  72.59   101.60
5   87.46   114.01  95.43   81.56   105.42  114.87  107.38  112.26  92.87   98.49
6   92.08   98.56   89.17   70.27   109.67  97.68   72.25   115.58  87.22   107.08
7   121.09  108.67  129.59  80.44   114.33  91.82   87.97   94.02   99.55   107.16
8   81.88   124.65  115.64  74.20   136.81  145.24  130.40  102.28  83.84   127.83
9   97.65   131.30  110.31  126.22  113.38  120.63  106.22  142.97  108.63  114.32
```

this is codes I wrote

```
import numpy as np

inpath = r'C:\Users\10696\Desktop\access\6\app.txt'
kk = np.loadtxt(inpath)
kk = kk[:, 1:]
kk = kk.flatten()
kk
```

[image]

**the result is**
[image]

Comment: numpy is a nice but very heavy library: it is overkill here.

Comment: You have changed the source data to fit your code (you added 0 at the start of the first line). Normally, one would write code to suit the input data format

Answer (score 0):

A very "manual" and "raw" way to achieve your needs.

```py
import csv

result = []
with open("test.csv") as f:
    # The delimiter parameter is the different CSV separators
    data = csv.reader(f, delimiter=" ")  
    for i in data:
    # This is because I copied your csv contents into a csv file, 
    # but it is not a standard csv format, there are multiple 
    # spaces between each column, if your csv is standard, 
    # then there is no need to make redundant judgments, just
        result.extend(_ for _ in i[1:] if _)
        # result.extend(i[1:]) # like this
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

The question describes the output as being a list of floating point values but actually shows a list of strings. Let's assume that floats are required.

The source file is interesting because the first line has a different structure to the second and subsequent lines. They appear to have some kind of "index" value which is **not** required in the output.

This means that the first line in the input file has to be dealt with slightly differently to the others.

Therefore (with no imports):

```
FILENAME = '/Volumes/G-Drive/data.csv'

def get_tokens(data, separator):
    yield next(data).split(separator)
    for line in data:
        yield line.split(separator)[1:]

def genlist(filename, separator=None):
    _list = []
    with open(filename) as data:
        for tokens in get_tokens(data, separator):
            _list.extend(map(float, tokens))
    return _list

print(genlist(FILENAME))
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you for all your helpful input. I have figured it out using a lot of trial and error as usual.
Here is the solution i eventually ended up with:

```
data = []
datafile = open('data.csv', 'r')

for line in datafile:
    entries = line.strip().split(',')
    for entry in entries:
        values = entry.strip().split('\n')
        for value in values:
            data.append(float(value))
```

[My final solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Vw1k.png)

Answer (score -1):

If there's no row numbers in the file then with python's standard libraries simple solution could be something like this:

```py
data = []
with open('data.csv') as input_file:
    for row in input_file:
        for value in row.strip().split():
            data.append(float(value))

print(data)
```

- 1: Open the file
- 2: Loop rows from the file
- 3: Strip() removes non printable characters like newline from the start and end of the file
- 4: Split() splits the stripped row into a "list"
- 5: Loop the splitted list and append values converted to floats to the data list

Comment: This would add the values at the beginning of the second and subsequent lines. That does not appear to be the requirement

Comment: @DarkKnight, There's a question for OP, does he really have the row numbers in his data. If you look the image op attached in the unedited question there's no row numbers. I tried to elaborate in my answer that this simple solution would work without the line numbers.

Comment: I can't see anything that contradicts the data format shown in the question

Comment: Here's the original question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76561778/1. Imho @prayson-w-daniel over edited the question. There's an image without line numbers and the list requested is indeed floats.

Comment: I work with what I see - not what I imagine. If the input data are not as shown in the question then it's up to OP to correct it. Editors should not make assumptions